# How does <picture> tag work with two sources?

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design

I need some help to understand why would someone load images like this in a web page? I mean the two  tags and the  tag at the end.

1. How is decided to which image to be loaded?
2. Is there a framework behind it?
3. Does it mean it loads both images and switches between them on different resolutions?

   ```
       <picture>
           <!--[if IE 9]><video style="display:none;"><![endif]-->
           <source srcset="<?php echo get_page_thumbnail('800x690', FALSE, TRUE); ?>" media="(max-width: 960px)">
           <source srcset="<?php echo get_page_thumbnail('9000x9000', FALSE, TRUE); ?>" media="(min-width: 960px)">
           <!--[if IE 9]></video><![endif]-->
           <img srcset="<?php echo get_page_thumbnail('9000x9000', TRUE, TRUE); ?>" alt="<?php echo get_page_title(); ?>" />          
       </picture>
   ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_picture.asp

The  tag gives web developers more flexibility in specifying image resources.

The most common use of the  element will be for art direction in responsive designs. Instead of having one image that is scaled up or down based on the viewport width, multiple images can be designed to more nicely fill the browser viewport.

The  element holds two different tags: one or more  tags and one  tag.

The  element has the following attributes:

- srcset (required) - defines the URL of the image to show
- media - accepts any valid media query that would normally be defined in a CSS
- sizes - defines a single width descriptor, a single media query with width descriptor, or a comma-delimited list of media queries with a width descriptor
- type - defines the MIME type

The browser will use the attribute values to load the most appropriate image. The browser will use the first  element with a matching hint and ignore any following  tags.